# Angular: Get values greater than 100 in array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display the length of items in my array that are greater than 100 by calling a function. I keep getting this error **"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".** Please help.

html

```
<div><p> {{getIssuesCount()}} </p></div>
```

ts

```
 getIssuesCount() {
    const issuesCount = this.wells.filter(wells => wells.totalCost > 100)
    return issuesCount.length
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It means `wells` is undefined. You should either put `this.wells?.filter(wells => wells.totalCost > 100)` or define it before (`this.wells = []`)

Comment: you can not use 'safe operator' in code, but you can use ternary operator: `issues=this.wells?this.wells.filter(...):[]` or use some "bizarro" like `(this.wells || []).filter(...)`